# Powering leds from arduino with adapter

Tags: arduino-uno, power, led, current, adapter

Sorry for having (again) a beginners question, but I was wondering something.

If I would want to drive like 20-30 LEDs from an Arduino (Uno), and I want to use an external adapter (12V, 1A), going into the Arduino, in what way I should drive the LEDs?

Problems I see:

- I cannot connect too many LEDs per pin (max 20mA per pin)
- I cannot connect too many LEDs per 'group' (I have to find out which pins are connected to what groups)
- I cannot connect too many LEDS in total because of the max. 200 mA per VCC/GND (there are 2 or 3 GNDs, so that should be ok)
- Using a relay/transistor etc, but how do I get the power? (there are also only 2 VCCs for 200 mA max)

So my basic question: how can I use the 1A from my adapter?

Comment: How precisely do you want to control the LEDs?

Comment: Have you considered using a driver that works with 12V?

Comment: I just read about a darlington IC (ULN8023) ... so probably that's the best way to do ... but I haven't found yet how to connect the 12V 1A adapter (I mean it will go into the Arduino), but how to connect / get that power to the LED ' chains' ?

Comment: Using relay module if you don't want to controle every single led could be a good aproach like this one - http://arduinobasics.blogspot.com.br/2014/09/relay-module.html

Comment: @AndrewPaes Well I don't need to control them one by one, but I want to have quite some possibilities, so a relay is a bit annoying to use in this case. I would need many.

Comment: drive each control group with an n-chan mosfet disconnecting the ground; cheaper than relays and silent. be prepared to use resistors to balance R,G, and B LED's "brightness"

Comment: @Majenko ... I'm thinking about a ULN8023 ... can I use the VIn to power the LEDs (and having 12V, 1A, or a bit less) ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just found out about the  ULN8023 (can I use the VIn to power the LEDs (and having 12V, 1A, or a bit less) ?

Comment: I don't mean what hardware you think you want to use - I mean what do you want the LEDs to *do*?

Comment: @Majenko ... I want for Christmas to make some wooden small '2D'  cardboard tree, put LEDs in it, and making the LEDs go around, or flash on/off in groups, maybe add some Christmas tune along

Comment: Do you want individual control of each and every LED? Or will having, say, 6 groups of LEDs that all react together be sufficient?

Comment: @Majenko ... initially I had the plan to control every LED, but I don't want it to become a too complicated project (I would have to use 74HC595 probably), so I stick with like 6 groups or so.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please say what can be improved (this also applies to all my other answers you downvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is group the LEDs together into chains that *almost* add up to the voltage of the power supply.

If you have LEDs with a 2V forward voltage (typical red LEDs) you could have up to say 5 per chain.

Each chain, since it only has 20mA or so maximum, can be driven with a simple small transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUptfV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Connect the 12V to either VIN or the barrel jack, and also drive the LED chain through a suitable resistor (R=V/I = (12 - (Num LEDs * Forward Voltage)) / 0.02). You can have as many chains as your supply can provide current for.

Comment: That sounds good ... would it be useful to use the ULN8023 (instead of the transistors)?

Comment: (and where does the maximum of 20mA per chain comes from? I would say 20 mA (per LED) * 5 LEDs = 100 mA)

Comment: Being darlingtons you get a larger voltage drop than just a transistor. You may not get it quite as bright. Other than that, it could be a convenient way of reducing component count (a chip instead of transistors)

Comment: Components in series have the same current but sum the voltages. Components in parallel have the same voltage but sum the current. The LEDs are in series, so they share the same current - 20mA, but sum their voltage - 2V each is 10V, leaving 2V for the transistor and the resistor.

Comment: Oh off course (now I feel really stupid).